QtDesigner растяжение виджетов
Помогите разобраться с растяжением виджетов.
Хочется, чтобы нижний виджет растягивался на всё окно приложения. И все виджеты делали это также.
Перепробовала несколько вариантов и ничего не выходит. Есть виджет нижний - выделен цветом для наглядности, его я добавила в Layout и в политике размеров виджета, как я поняла указала верно - Expanding, однако при растягивании экрана ничего не происходит.
У центрального виджета также указаны размеры: Expanding. Максимальные размеры огромные. Но всё равно не работает.



Nastya, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Добавьте в тело вопроса модуль name.ui

Тогда нужен пожалуй vboxlayout, не?
